# T-SQL Arithmetic overflow: which column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In MS SQL Server 2005, when encountering an "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric" during an INSERT, is it possible to discover which column's input value caused the error?

There seems to be a number of similar conversion errors that don't report which column provoked the trouble. This makes fixing mistakes rather difficult in huge queries. Is there some other way to deal with this?

Comment: it use to happen to me also, but with binary or string data truncated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, No, you can't get the error message to show you in which column is failing. But, if you know what you are inserting you should be able to find where the error is.
Why don't you put the table structure and the insert query.

Comment: Thanks, I can indeed find the find the problem field manually (though this is in the context of a web app, which makes it more tedious); it just seems ridiculous that I should have to bother.